# node.js mongoose subfield in a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been working with node.js and mongoose for sometime and I am hitting a wall. I have a database with 20,000 documents and when i search the database from the cli it works fine.

```
db.Tickets.find({ "Customers.Customer.CustomerID" : '123123123' })
```

This returns 256 results

Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Define collection and schema for Ticket
var Ticket = new Schema({
    UserName: {
        type: String
    },
    Status: {
        type: String
    },
    TicketNumber: {
        type: Number
    },
    Name: {
        type: String
    },
    Description: {
        type: String
    },
    TicketTypeName: {
        type: String
    },
    DueDate: {
        type: Date
    },
    MapCollectDate : {
        type: Date
    },
    NumberofUsersAffected : {
        type: Number
    },
    DNNumber : {
        type : String
    },
    RevisionDate : {
        type : Date
    },
    CommercialImpact : {
        type: String
    },
    Customers :[{
        Customer: [{
            CustomerID: Number,
            CustomerName: String
        }]
    }],
```

Although if I test this in node.js using mongoose. I can't get it to return anything

I have a generic search that works

```
Ticket.find(function (err, tickets){
```

But can't get the specific search to work.

I am Connecting to Mongo

```
const config = require('./db');
//const Course = require('./models/Course');
//const CourseRoute = require('./routes/CourseRoute');
const Ticket = require('./models/Ticket');
const TicketRoute = require('./routes/TicketRoute');

const PORT = 4000;

mongoose.connect(config.DB).then(
    () => {console.log('Connected to MongoDB') },
    err => { console.log('Error connecting to MongoDB' +err)
    });
```

Output of the log

```
Your node js server is running on PORT: 4000
Connected to MongoDB
Connected to MySQL
```

My Route End point

```
router.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
        Ticket.find({ "Customers.Customer.CustomerID" : global.auth_username }, function(err, ticket) {            
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(tickets);
        }
    });
});
```

Also tried without the variable

```
router.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
        Ticket.find({ "Customers.Customer.CustomerID" : "123123123" }, function(err, ticket) {            
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(tickets);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I forgot to connect to Mongoose before running query

```
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL, mongoOptions)
    .then(() => {
        // do your thing here
    })
```

Comment: Ticket.find(function (err, tickets){ 

this works fine. I get the data from Mongo.

Comment: Well `Ticket.find` shoudn't work if you have not connect to mongoose before.
`db.Tickets.find({ "Customers.Customer.CustomerID" : '123123123' })` is the command when you are already connected in the mongo server

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions

Comment: Need some help here

Answer (score 0):

You had over a year to figured this out, and I am sure that you did so, but either way it seems that you have a typo in your code. The callback parameter is named `ticket` - `function(err, ticket) {`, whereas you are logging `tickets` - `res.json(tickets);`. In the generic test you correctly wrote `tickets` - `Ticket.find(function (err, tickets){`, which is probably why it worked.

The takeaway lesson here is - use debugging tools instead of logging, makes it easier to catch such problems.

Also, it would be appropriate to answer your own question once you've figured it out. But given that this is probably completely useless, you might as well delete it. Cheers!